# create classname with multiple css classes not working

Tags: html, css, styles

I have the follwoing css styles in css file

```
.paddingRight.tiny {
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}

.paddingRight.small {
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.paddingRight.medium {
    padding-right: 1.5em;
}

.paddingLeft.tiny {
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.paddingLeft.small {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.paddingLeft.medium {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

And the html code is looks like below,

```
<div className="paddingRight small paddingLeft tiny">
    //Some content goes here
</div>
```

If I mention class name like this, css not applied properly.

expected css class:

```
paddingRight.small and .paddingLeft.tiny
```

actual class:

```
paddingRight.small and .paddingLeft.small
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: Is this HTML or JSX? You have it tagged as HTML, but the syntax you've included is JSX.

Comment: i have tried in JSX. but the same behaviour is happening in normal HTML and CSS also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `className` syntax is for JSX code, a JavaScript language that looks like HTML for the sake of simplicity for developers, but they are **NOT** the same. I don't believe it will lead to an error in the console, but it will not render the styles. For HTML, you should use the `class` syntax. You also cannot have `.` in the name of a class because this is an identifier for a class. You usually use a `-` or camelCase.

I've added the red background class just to show you the code works.

```css
.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.paddingRight-tiny {
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}

.paddingRight-small {
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.paddingRight-medium {
    padding-right: 1.5em;
}

.paddingLeft-tiny {
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.paddingLeft-small {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.paddingLeft-medium {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="red paddingRight-small paddingLeft-tiny">
    <p>Some content goes here...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have in your html your div have 4 different classes. which changing one will change everything.
you should try:

```
<div className="paddingRight">
 <div className="small">
 //something
 </div>
 <div className="tiny">
 //something
 </div>
</div>
<div className="paddingLeft">
 <div className="small">
 //something
 </div>
 <div className="tiny">
 //something
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to create another one div for css class. I think i can rename the css styles like below, `paddingRight-small` will fix this issue.

Comment: if you write <div class="a b c d">hello</div> then in css changing a will change b,c and d as well. I hope it make sense.